# Progress Dialog usage with Thread

Tags: android, dialog, progressdialog

**here is my code,**

```
public ProgressDialog loadingdialog;
public void ShowManager() {
    //do something
}
public void startScan() {
      loadingdialog = ProgressDialog.show(WifiManagementActivity.this,
                                              "","Scanning Please Wait",true);
      new Thread() {
          public void run() {
              try {
                    sleep(4000);
                    ShowManager();

              } catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.e("threadmessage",e.getMessage());
              }
              loadingdialog.dismiss();
          }
      }.start();
    }

startScan();
```

A basic progressdialog show function, but on the line where ShowManager() is called, getting error ,

```
01-07 23:11:36.081: ERROR/threadmessage(576): Only the original thread 
that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

---

**EDIT:**

ShowManager() is a function that change the view elements. shortly something like,

```
  public void ShowManager() 
  {
      TextView mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifiText);
      mainText.setText("editted");

  }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the answer. I don't like to answer my own question but maybe [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-threads-and-progressdialog) will help someone else. We cannot update most UI objects while in a separate thread. We must create a handler and update the view inside it.

```
public ProgressDialog loadingdialog;
  private Handler handler = new Handler() {
          @Override
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              loadingdialog.dismiss();
              ShowManager();

          }
      };
  public void ShowManager()
  {
      TextView mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifiText);
      mainText.setText("editted");
  }
  public void startScan() {
      loadingdialog = ProgressDialog.show(WifiManagementActivity.this,
                                          "","Scanning Please Wait",true);
      new Thread() {
          public void run() {
              try {
                  sleep(4000);
                  handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

              } catch(Exception e) {
                  Log.e("threadmessage",e.getMessage());
              }
          }
      }.start();
  }

  startScan();
```

Answer (score 4):

use this instead of just loadingdialog.dismiss()

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
         loadingdialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: I have no problem about showing and dismissing progressdialog, that's working, I'm getting error on showmanager() function.

Comment: so instead of loadingdialog.dismiss put showmanager() in above answer, that  should work

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to dismiss the dialog from the thread, while it was created in the main UI thread. Try moving the `ProgressDialog.show` statement inside the Thread. I would prefer using AsyncTask as they are much simpler to manage as in this [example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: progressdialog is working, I'm getting error on the line where I called showmanager().

Answer (score 0):

something like this it's 'ok':

```
public void startScan() {
  new Thread() {
      public void run() {
  loadingdialog = ProgressDialog.show(WifiManagementActivity.this,
                                          "","Scanning Please Wait",true);
          try {
                sleep(4000);
                ShowManager();

          } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("threadmessage",e.getMessage());
          }
          loadingdialog.dismiss();
      }
  }.start();
}
```

note the position of ProgressDialog.show(...), here the dialog.dismiss() is called in the thread that created the dialog.
but the cleanest way to achive that it's by using [AsynTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)